# Squid Proxy with ten of thousands of cache peer

Tags: proxy, squid, sysadmin

I tried having 20 lines of cache_peer and its working correctly, however when i added ten of thousands of cache_peer, and i cant really connect to it. Any idea why ?

My goal is to have hundred or thousands of authenticated users connect to my ProxyServer and my ProxyServer would then forward to another proxy provider (oxylab, smartproxy, etc). Not sure if Squid is the correct choice for this case !

Comment: I think this might be possible but what are you trying to solve? Looks for me like an X and Y issue

Comment: @djdomi like i mentioned above, i tried having 20lines of cache_peer, its working perfectly fine, now i added 10thousands line of cache_peers, its not working anymore
`cache_peer HOSTNAME parent PORT 0 name=host_1 login=USERNAME:PASSWORD no-query proxy-only round-robin`
`cache_peer HOSTNAME parent PORT 0 name=host_1 login=USERNAME:PASSWORD no-query proxy-only round-robin`
.....
and so on.

My use case would be
users can connect to myproxyserver:9999:username:pw and i will forward to another proxy provider.

Comment: if you plan 10k users on a single server its a planned failure. Furthermore i would suggest to think about, to use LDAP or similar instead of plain config. And Also "Does not work anymore" is not an error description show us what is not working

Comment: @djdomi not quite 10k users. But allow users(could be 1 or 10 for now) to connect to my ProxyServer and i can randomly forward the traffic to one of these 10k cache_peer. It says TCP_DENIED/407, but after like 10min, it connected but really really slow. So i am not sure if Squid if the right tools

Comment: i would suggest to split the config first, with lets say 1/8 and starting adding them to verify the situation, i please you to join the chat on https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126791/thechat